# Ruby on Rails - Update Parent Field upon Child Creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a two models, `Submission` (the parent) and `SubmissionDetail` (the child). `Submission` has a field called `status`, which can either be Incomplete, Pending, Approved, or Disapproved. When you create a new `Submission`, `status` is automatically set to Incomplete. The child has a foreign key of `:submission_id`.

What I would like to happen is when a new `SubmissionDetail` is created, its parent's status will automatically be changed to "Pending." Not sure how to go about this. For example, I've read a little about `touch` in the model, but I don't think that applies here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably make use of [ActiveRecord's callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to update the parent whenever a new child is created.

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submission_details
end

class SubmissionDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submission

  after_create :set_parent_to_pending

  def set_parent_to_pending
    # child should always have a parent, but we need to check just in case
    submission.update(status: 'pending') unless submission.nil?
  end
end
```

The `after_create` callback will be run after the child record is created.

Comment: Never knew about after_create! Thanks so much, that worked in my project. I will definitely save that link you provided.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly handle this by hooking `create`, but then you're not hooking `update` and certain actions won't propagate back to `Submission`. You're also littering your persistence layer with business logic and coupling models.

My preference, avoiding the creation of service objects, would be to use [`after_touch`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-touch):

```
class SubmissionDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submission, touch: true
end

class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :submission_details
  after_touch :pending!
protected
  def pending!
    self.status = 'pending'
    save!
  end
end
```

This keeps the logic out of `SubmissionDetail` and keeps `Submission` responsible for keeping its own status up to date.

Note that if you end up having to manipulate status based on flow and conditions like this a lot, you really want to look into integrating a state machine.

Comment: I like the idea of keeping the `Submission` responsible for its own state, but as written this will set the `Submission` state to `pending` each time the `SubmissionDetail` is changed (not just on create), which may not be the desired behavior. What if the state of the parent `Submission` depended on some attribute of the `SubmissionDetail`-- AFAIK the `touch` callback does not have access to the record which originally fired it (i.e. the `SubmissionDetail`)

Comment: @carlosramireziii True. There are a lot of edges that aren't being considered here, which is why I generally prefer writing more object-oriented code to handle business logic and letting my persistence layer focus on persistence. Rails models do enough as is.

Answer (score 1):

Touch just updates the updated_at column to the current time. You can just add an after_create hook:

```
class SubmissionDetail < AR

  belongs_to :submission
  after_create :set_pending

  private

  def set_pending
    submission.update_attributes(state: "Pending") # or whatever random method
  end

end
```